# Keyboard and Mouse not working after wake up; independent of OS

Tags: keyboard, motherboard, mouse, sleep

When I did a full reinstall of Windows and Linux Mint, I changed all the settings of the mainboard to boot in UEFI and turned off all compatibility settings like xHCI hand-off and so on.

I was at first very happy with these settings because the computer would boot faster and finally sleep would also work with Linux Mint on my system.

I can use the keyboard or mouse to wake up the machine, but after that both are not working anymore, meaning I have to press the reset button and restart the computer.

It behaves the same on Windows 10 and Linux.

I suspect another weird thing might have something to do with my issue. From the first day I had my PC (in BIOS mode), if the PC was completely turned off, my mouse and keyboard wouldn't work in the OS. They would work fine in the bios. I again have to press the reset button and after the 2nd boot it would work just fine.

I suspect the mainboard to have either an issue or a bad setting. But what could it be?

Help is very appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: do you have a BIOS update or a firmware update you can make?

Comment: No, I'm already using the most recent version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone has the same issue, I just wanted to post my solution to the problem.

Of all the settings in the bios, I had to set USB 3.0 Support to "Auto".

South Bridge --> USB 3.0 Support --> Auto.

If you set the value to "Enabled", it won't work. Only "Auto" works.